# Changing Variable in another class iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, variables

I have follow countless similar situations on here ( stack overflow ). I have applied those write ups for my situation and have come close but haven't found a solution that seems work for me. As this is something very trivial I am baffled at how it isn't working for me.

Anyways, I am trying to set a Int variable from inside the appDelegate class and the variable actually belongs, if that is the right word, to another class (mainViewController).

For the MainViewController class .h file I have

```
@interface MainWindowControllerViewController :... { 
   int relayState;
}
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) int relayState;
```

For the MainViewController class .m file I have

```
@implementation MainWindowControllerViewController
@synthesize relayState = _relayState;

-(void)quickConnect { // Call for all UI bypassing and quick kill

NSLog(@"Relay state in MainWindow = %d", relayState);

    if (_relayState == 1) {
        NSLog(@"TURNING ON KILL SWITCH");
        self.writeData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"e"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        [sensor write:sensor.activePeripheral data:writeData];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"TURNING OFF KILL SWITCH");
        self.writeData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"o"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        [sensor write:sensor.activePeripheral data:writeData];
    }
}
```

For the appDelegate.h file I have

```
#import "MainWindowControllerViewController.h"
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    MainWindowControllerViewController *relayState;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) MainWindowControllerViewController *relayState;
```

Then for the appDelegate.m file I have

```
#import "MainWindowControllerViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize relayState = _relayState;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *) sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    NSLog(@" Calling application: %@", sourceApplication);
    NSLog(@" URL scheme: %@", [url scheme]);

    if ([sourceApplication isEqualToString:@"URL-Scheme-Test"]) {

        if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"TurnOffRelay"]) {

            _relayState =[[MainWindowControllerViewController alloc] init];
            _relayState.relayState = 1;
            NSLog(@"Relay State BEFORE = %d", _relayState.relayState);

        }

        return YES;

        if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"TurnOnRelay"]) {

            _relayState =[[MainWindowControllerViewController alloc] init];
            _relayState.relayState = 0;
            NSLog(@"Relay State BEFORE = %d", _relayState.relayState);

        }

        return YES;

    }

    else

        return NO;


}
```

This is pretty much it. When I do the logs I find that the relayState that I want to change the value of shows that I was able to change the value. But when I do the If statement above that checks weather the relayState is equal to 1 the variable is always 0.

I'm not the most proficient in Obj C. Some help would be appreciated! Thanks. I'll gladly answer any extra questions about code if needed.

Comment: For the purpose of this question, it would be better to not have two different things called relayState.

Answer (score 0):

You are kind of mixing some older style obj-c with how it usually looks currently and I think you are hiding a variable (one declaration is hiding another)

Take out:

```
{ 
   int relayState;
}
```

From your MainWindowControllerViewController  interface

Take out the `@synthesize` in the MainWindowControllerViewController implementation

Don't use `_relayState` (just use `relayState`)

Do the same with the MainWindowControllerViewController variable in the AppDelegate.

If that doesn't fix it, we need to see what is happening to the VC you are creating.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I believe is this line

```
 _relayState =[[MainWindowControllerViewController alloc] init];
```

You are initializing MainWindowControllerViewController in both the if blocks which is resetting the value to the default value (In this case 0) every time.

Comment: The line right below that one (in one case) says: `_relayState.relayState = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
MainWindowControllerViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainWindowControllerViewControllerIdentifier"];
vc.relayState = 1;
```

For the MainViewController class .h

`@interface MainWindowControllerViewController :... { 
   int relayState; //remove this line
}
@property (nonatomic) int relayState; //use this`

try this

Answer (score 0):

You are making a mistake that will create endless problems for you.

You have a property named relayState and an instance variable named relayState.

The property "relayState" is backed by an instance variable named _relayState. You have another instance variable named relayState. Two different variables. Assigning to self.relayState changes one, assigning to relayState changes the other. Don't do it.

Just get rid of the "int relayState;" and don't use @synthesize and you'll be fine. At least a lot finer than you are now. You can then either use self.relayState or _relayState. At least you will always know what you are doing.

PS. Having an int relayState and a MainWindowViewController* relayState is just asking for trouble. You seem to be intentionally trying to confuse yourself.

PS. You seem to do the same dangerous game with the writeData property/variable.